# Check if ENV property is declared in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In my Jenkins pipeline I have:

```
library 'my-shared-library'
pipeline {
  environment {
    MY_PROPERTY = 'ABC'
  }
}
```

In my shared library that is included in my Jenkins pipeline I use MY_PROPERTY as:

```
def someMethod() {
  def someText = "blah blah ${MY_PROPERTY}"
}
```

The problem is that I call someMethod() from many pipelines and in some pipelines MY_PROPERTY is not defined:

```
library 'my-shared-library'
pipeline {
  environment {
    
  }
}
```

so I receive following error:

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: MY_PROPERTY for class: my.comapny.mylib

I need a way to check if MY_PROPERTY was declared inside environemnt section or not, something like this:

```
def someMethod() {
  if is defined MY_PROPERTY then
    def someText = "blah blah ${MY_PROPERTY}"
  else
    def someText = "X"
}
```

How can I check if MY_PROPERTY was declared? If I try to access MY_PROPERTY and it was not declared in environments I receive:

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: MY_PROPERTY for class: my.comapny.mylib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're facing this issue because you use implicit env variable call. It's always a better choice to use an explicit env variable call like `env.MY_PROPERTY`. This way you can avoid the `No such property` exception, and when the env variable is not defined, you will get a `null` value instead. This way, you can make a simple check like:

```
def someMethod() {
  def someText = "blah blah ${env.MY_PROPERTY ?: 'foo'}"
}
```

which results in `blah blah foo` if `env.MY_PROPERTY` is not set.